# Delphi Xe - Thread and WebBrowser get source rersults in AV

Tags: delphi

I want to create a Thread that constantly monitors my WebBrowser to check if some text appears in page source. I have multiple WebBrowsers on the form, but I've made an SSCCE with only one WebBrowser (the AV is still present).

I even made a timer that waits 10 seconds after document is loaded and created thread on timer event (to make sure document is completed), but it seems not to be the problem. The AV is present whether the document is loaded or not. So the timer is not present in the example below. I've made step-by-step execution and the AV occurs where the comment is `iall.outerHTML`. iall seems to contain the right stuff, but calling outerHTML results is AV.

Can you find the error?

The Unit source code is below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ActiveX, StrUtils, MSHTML,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser, IOleCommandTarget)
    CurDispatch: IDispatch;
  private
    TFDocLoaded: Boolean;
    TFedAddress: String;
    function QueryStatus(CmdGroup: PGUID; cCmds: Cardinal; prgCmds: POleCmd;
      CmdText: POleCmdText): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Exec(CmdGroup: PGUID; nCmdID, nCmdexecopt: DWORD;
      const vaIn: OleVariant; var vaOut: OleVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
  published
    property FDocLoaded: Boolean read TFDocLoaded write TFDocLoaded;
    property FedAddress: String read TFedAddress write TFedAddress;
  end;

  TForm1 = class;

  TWatcherThread = class(TThread)
  private
    THBrowser: TForm1;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ABrowser: TForm1);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    MyWatcher: TWatcherThread;
    function checkIfThereIs(AWebBrowser: TWebBrowser): Boolean;
    function GetWebBrowserHTML(const ABrowser: TWebBrowser): String;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TWebBrowser.QueryStatus(CmdGroup: PGUID; cCmds: Cardinal; prgCmds: POleCmd; CmdText: POleCmdText): HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TWebBrowser.Exec(CmdGroup: PGUID; nCmdID, nCmdexecopt: DWORD; const vaIn: OleVariant; var vaOut: OleVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
  if nCmdID = OLECMDID_SHOWSCRIPTERROR then Result := S_OK;
end;

function TForm1.checkIfThereIs(AWebBrowser: TWebBrowser): Boolean;
var
  src: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    src := GetWebBrowserHTML(AWebBrowser);
    if PosEx('<span>Mail</span>', src) > 0 then Result := True;
  except
    on E : Exception do result := False;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.GetWebBrowserHTML(const ABrowser: TWebBrowser): String;
var
  iall: IHTMLElement;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    if not Assigned(ABrowser.Document) then Exit;
    if (ABrowser.Document AS IHTMLDocument2).body <> nil then
      begin
        iall := (ABrowser.Document AS IHTMLDocument2).body;
        while iall.parentElement <> nil do iall := iall.parentElement;
        Result := iall.outerHTML;  // <- here I get AV after doc is loaded
      end;
  except
    on E : Exception do //
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
  WB: TWebBrowser;
begin
  WB := TWebBrowser(ASender);
  if WB.CurDispatch = nil then WB.CurDispatch := pDisp;
  WB.FDocLoaded := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.yahoo.com');
  MyWatcher := TWatcherThread.Create(Self);
  with MyWatcher do
    begin
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
      Resume;
    end;
end;


constructor TWatcherThread.Create(ABrowser: TForm1);
begin
  THBrowser := ABrowser;
  inherited Create(True);
end;

procedure TWatcherThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
  pt: TWebBrowser;
begin
  inherited;
  repeat
    //parsing list of existing WebBrowsers -> for each do the following begin/end section
      begin
      if THBrowser.WebBrowser1.FDocLoaded = True then
        if THBrowser.checkIfThereIs(THBrowser.WebBrowser1) then // must be called this way (passing WebBrowser class to function) because in the original I have more than one WebBrowsers
          begin
            THBrowser.Label1.Caption := 'There is!';
            Break;
          end;
      end;
    Sleep(1000);
  until Terminated;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your problem is you have absolutely no thread protection or synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are breaking the VCL threading rules. All access to VCL controls must be made from the main thread.

You are also breaking the COM threading rules by calling methods of the COM web browser objects off the thread that created them.

It seems to me that the thread serves no purpose here and that you should simply do the work in `NavigateComplete2`.

I also wonder whether or not a visual component is the correct choice here. Do you need to display all these web pages, or are you crawling?

Comment: Indeed, I was about to mention I don't see a purpose to have this in a thread and then I saw your edit.

Comment: There are web pages that use ajax to update page (for example) and NavigateComplete2 doesn't trigger when updating. So I would like to know if some elements occurred in page. That's why I want a thread that monitors page source and if searched elements appear, some action should trigger.

Comment: All the same, you have to respect the threading rules. Perhaps you need to do everything in the main thread using a timer.

Comment: Thanks David! You've enlighten me.